# How can i create JSON array of JSON objects in ruby from a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to loop through some `video` objects and i am trying to build a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[{"event_name":"video_completed","object_id":123456789}]
```

I created a method to do this:

```
def self.getEngagementRules(videos)

    rules = []

    videos.each do |video|

        rule = {
            event_name: "video_completed",
            object_id: video.image_hash.to_i
        }

        rules << rule.to_json
    end

    rules
end
```

I am creating hashes and then turning them into JSON and appending it to my array `rules` but when i run:

```
puts rules
```

i get `{"event_name":"video_completed","object_id":123456789}`

instead of `[{"event_name":"video_completed","object_id":123456789}]`

What is the correct way of doing this so i can loop through multiple videos and get my desired result.

It should be able to handle multiple videos and output:

```
[{"event_name":"video_completed","object_id":123456789}, {"event_name":"video_completed","object_id":123456789}]
```

Comment: Your code works fine, aren't you printing `rule` instead of `rules` by mistake? Also, each element in your array will be a string representing a JSON `["{\"event_name\":\"video_completed\",\"object_id\":1234}"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to first compose a ruby array and then convert it to JSON:

```
rules = videos.map do |video|
  {
    event_name: "video_completed",
    object_id: video.image_hash.to_i
   }
end
rules.to_json
```

`.each` should only be used when you are only concerned with the side effects of the loop and not the return value.

Otherwise you should be using [`.map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), `.inject`, `.each_with_object` etc which signify to other programmers that you care about the return value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'side effects of the loop'?

Comment: For example in ERB templates you use `.each` since you are outputting to a string buffer and the return value is not used.

Comment: Thanks! I might need to go through my project and see where else i can use map instead of each haha

Answer (score 1):

Your code works right, you have an array but `puts` prints each element of the array in a separate line

```
puts [1, 2, 3]

1
2
3
```